# Validation php code error W3C

Tags: php, html, validation, xhtml, w3c-validation

I have problem with tr when I valdite in w3c it gives me

```
        //Display table of users
        echo "<table cellspacing='15'>";
        echo "<th>Id </th>";
        echo "<th>First Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Gender</th>";
        echo "<th>Type of Residence</th>";
        echo "<th>Level of Education</th>";
        echo "<th>Favorite time of Day</th>";
        echo "<th>Favorite Quote</th>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";    
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['residence'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['education'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['favorite_time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['quote'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";   
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

**this is w3c errors**

Validation Output: 6 Errors

Line 13, Column 30: document type does not allow element "th" here; assuming missing "tr" start-tag
        Id First NameLast Name…
✉
 Line 13, Column 199: document type does not allow element "tr" here
… of DayFavorite Quote1AngelaSmith…
✉
The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

Line 13, Column 359: document type does not allow element "tr" here
…but obscurity is forever.2JosephLinburgh

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

Line 13, Column 577: document type does not allow element "tr" here
… sure about the universe.3RonMonaco

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

Line 13, Column 771: document type does not allow element "tr" here
…you were to live forever.4JeanKelly

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

Line 13, Column 960: end tag for "tr" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
…t happens to you while you're busy making other plans.   
✉
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

Line 13, Column 27: start tag was here
        Id First NameLast Name…

please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of the error message describes the error rather clearly: you need to emit a `<tr>` tag before the first cell (first `<th>` tag here). Table cells are allowed only in table rows, i.e. `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you need, at the very least, `tr` to put your `td`s in...thats what it says "assuming missing "tr" start-tag"